# According to Catholicism, does God want everyone to be Catholic?

Tags: catholicism, nature-of-god, soteriology

According to Catholicism, does God want all humans to be Catholic?  And if everyone became Catholic, would Satan be abolished? Is this acknowledged in the Bible or elsewhere?

Comment: "Does this need to be directed to one denomination instead of all of Christianity?" Yes.

Comment: Some denominations believe that bad Christians may go to hell, so Satan would still have his evil works in place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Does God desire that all men be Catholic?

The answer to the O.P. is fundamentally “yes:” the Church teaches that it is the *Catholic* Church—that is, the universal Church—and hence that God calls all people to be members.

[*Lumen Gentium*](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_const_19641121_lumen-gentium_en.html) [LG], Vatican II’s dogmatic constitution on the Church, puts it as follows:

> All men are called to belong to the new people of God [i.e., the Church]. Wherefore this people, while remaining one and only one, is to be spread throughout the whole world and must exist in all ages, so that the decree of God's will may be fulfilled…. It follows that though there are many nations there is but one people of God, which takes its citizens from every race, making them citizens of a kingdom which is of a heavenly rather than of an earthly nature…. All men are called to be part of this catholic [i.e., universal] unity of the people of God which in promoting universal peace presages it (LG 13).

By stating this, the Catholic Church does not intend in any way to belittle the authentic goodness in persons who are not fully in communion with the Church—that is, non-Catholic Christians, and even the non-baptized who seek the truth sincerely.

Briefly, fully-fledged members of the Catholic Church have access to all of the means of salvation that Christ gave to his Church:

> They are fully incorporated in the society of the Church who, possessing the Spirit of Christ accept her entire system and all the means of salvation given to her, and are united with her as part of her visible bodily structure and through her with Christ, who rules her through the Supreme Pontiff and the bishops (LG 14).

However, other Christians enjoy a certain communion with the Catholic Church:

> For men who believe in Christ and have been truly baptized are in communion with the Catholic Church even though this communion is imperfect (Vatican II’s decree on ecumenism, [Unitatis redintegratio](http://www.vatican.va/archive/hist_councils/ii_vatican_council/documents/vat-ii_decree_19641121_unitatis-redintegratio_en.html), 3).

Moreover, the Church recognizes a certain unity with those non-baptized persons who nevertheless believe in God (especially the Jewish People, as well as Muslims), and even with members of other religious who nevertheless seek the truth. (See [*Catechism of the Catholic Church* [CCC]](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a9p3.htm), Nos. 839-845.)

Even so, all men are *ordered* to the Catholic faith:

> And there belong to or are related to (*ordinantur*)* it in various ways, the Catholic faithful, all who believe in Christ, and indeed the whole of mankind, for all men are called by the grace of God to salvation (LG 15).

It is certainly the design of the Creator that all men should be members of his Church, while on earth; in any event, all men who are saved will be members of that Church in Heaven. (See [CCC 954](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p123a9p5.htm).)

## Will Satan be banish once that is accomplished

As far as the other parts of the O.P.’s question, Satan will not be definitively “banished” or defeated until the end of the world, because, of course, the Evil One is still able to tempt even the followers of Jesus while they are on earth. This idea is expressed, for example, in [Revelation 20:10](http://biblehub.com/revelation/20-10.htm):

> and the devil who had deceived them was thrown into the lake of fire and sulfur where the beast and the false prophet were, and they will be tormented day and night forever and ever (ESV).

(Note that this defeat takes place immediately after the Millennium, which, according to most Catholic exegetes, refers to the age of the Church; i.e., the age we are in now, between the First and Second Coming of Christ.)

## Some Biblical texts to support the Catholic view

Regarding the Biblical basis for God’s desire that all men be Catholic, there are a number of passages that could be recalled. For example, there is [Acts 2:47](http://biblehub.com/acts/2-47.htm):

> And the Lord added to their number day by day those who were being saved.

The Church considers itself to be in historic continuity with the Church of the Apostles. This passage shows that God considers membership in the Church as necessary for salvation.**

If we then consider [1 Timothy 2:4](http://biblehub.com/1_timothy/2-4.htm), we see that God desires that all men be saved:

> [God] desires all people to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth (ESV).

It follows that God wants all men to have access to the means of salvation, which is the Church.

In a similar vein, we have Romans [8:30](http://biblehub.com/romans/8-30.htm):

> And those whom he predestined he also called, and those whom he called he also justified, and those whom he justified he also glorified (ESV).

In Catholic thought, “predestination” is precisely the ordering by God of His creatures to Himself (i.e. His desire that we be saved).*** St. Paul affirms that being predestined also entails being *called* (ἐκάλεσεν), which is precisely what it means to be a member of the Church (ἐκκλησία, which even comes from the same root as “to call” in Greek).

---

* The official translation reads “related to,” as can be seen, but “ordered to” (that is, directed toward) would better represent the original Latin *ordinantur*.

** It is important, however, not to understand the Catholic Church’s necessity for salvation so extremely as to fall into rigorism. The Church does indeed teach that “outside the Church there is no salvation” (see [CCC 846](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/_P29.HTM)), but the Church also insists that those who are outside the visible confines of the Church through no fault of their own still have the opportunity for salvation.

*** Generally, however, in Catholic theology—which, at least in the West, follows St. Augustine’s terminology—the “predestined” refers to those whom God, in his omniscience, knows will be saved, whereas the “reprobate” refers to those will not be saved. This should not be taken to mean that God *forces* people to be saved or condemned; God always respects our freedom. The Calvinistic idea that God predestines people to Hell is quite foreign to Catholic teaching.

Comment: How is the Church united "with members of other religious who nevertheless seek the truth"? "Jesus Christ did not, in point of fact, institute a Church to embrace several communities similar in nature" (Pope Leo XIII's encyclical on the unity of the Church, [_Satis Cognitum_](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Leo13/l13satis.htm) §4). It seems the Vatican II documents you quote are saying that although God desires everyone to be part of the Church; they already are, in various degrees.

Comment: Also, being a seeker of truth is not sufficient for salvation or membership in the Church; one must be "baptized and profess the true faith" (Pope Pius XII's [_Mystici Corporis Christi_](https://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_29061943_mystici-corporis-christi.html) §22) to be united to the Church.

Comment: @Geremia Vatican II asserts that there are differing degrees of participation in the Catholic Church. The Church of Christ  _subsists in_ (i.e., has the fullness of being in) the Catholic Church (to quote the famous expression from _Lumen Gentium_), but that does not prevent other bodies from having an imperfect union with the (unique, Catholic) Church.

Comment: @Geremia I did not claim (nor does Vatican II claim) that seeking the truth is sufficient for salvation. (In fact, the _condicio sina qua non_ for salvation is _sanctifying grace_.) However, salvation is _offered_ (by extraordinary means, evidently) to those who, through no fault of their own, are not in full union with the Church.

Comment: @Geremia Pius XII is presupposing that baptism is offered (and accepted or rejected) with full knowledge and freedom. The idea of an implicit baptism of desire is at least as old as the discovery of the Americas—when Catholic theologians discovered that millions of people had never heard the Gospel, and, obviously, could not be held accountable for not being baptized.

Comment: Let me cite "Crossing the Threshold of Hope" by John Paul II: "The position of Saint Thomas is, in fact, well known: He is so consistent in his respect for conscience that he maintains that it is wrong for one to make an act of faith in Christ if in one's conscience one is convinced, however absurdly, that it is wrong to carry out such an act (cf. Summa Theologiae 1-2. 19. 5). If man is admonished by his conscience-even if an erroneous conscience, but one whose voice appears to him as unquestionably true-he must always listen to it."

Comment: Does that mean that if someone is truly convinced that the Catholic Church is wrong, then the Catholic Church does not want such a person to be Catholic?

Comment: @gaazkam Thank you for the reference to St. Thomas. I was looking for that one, and then forgot to keep looking.

Comment: @gaazkam Regarding whether people convinced that the Church is wrong should join the Church: as long as their (erroneous) conviction persists, then they should follow their conviction, even if that means not joining the Church. The Church, obviously, desires that such persons could be convinced otherwise, since they are missing out on all of the benefits of being members of the Church.

Comment: How, in this case, should a Catholic regard the Syllabus of Errors issued by Pope St. Pius IX, which condemns, among others, that "every man is free to embrace and profess that religion which, guided by the light of reason, he shall consider true"? http://www.ewtn.com/library/PAPALDOC/P9SYLL.HTM

Comment: @gaazkam That condemnation has to be understood in its historical context. Bl. Pius IX had to contend with _indifferentism_, which asserts, basically, that it does not matter which religion one belongs to. The condemnation does not intend to say that people must be coerced into embracing the Catholic Faith. Also, it is simply not considering people’s subjectivity. It is true that people are not “free” to join a different religion—that is, objectively, everyone is obligated to belong to the Church of Christ. They may, however, not be aware of the obligation or able to fulfill it.